# Frama-C in Cygwin failed to load plug-in

Tags: ocaml, frama-c, opam

I have succesfully installed OCaml Environment on Windows([OCaml for Windows](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/)) and installed Frama-C through `opam` utility.

Execute `frama-c -version` returns correct version.

But `frama-c` can not load plug-in module, e.g. `wp`.
Execute

```
$ frama-c
```

returns

```
[kernel] User Error: cannot load plug-in 'num.core': cannot load module
 Details: error loading shared library: Dynlink.Error (Dynlink.Cannot_open_dll "Failure(\"flexdll error: cannot relocate RELOC_REL32, target is too far: ffffffff6a110d73  000000006a110d73\")")
[kernel] User Error: cannot load plug-in 'zip': cannot load module
  Details: error loading shared library: Dynlink.Error (Dynlink.Cannot_open_dll "Failure(\"flexdll error: cannot relocate RELOC_REL32, target is too far: fffffffe488b648d  00000000488b648d\")")
[kernel] User Error: cannot load plug-in 'why3': cannot load module
  Details: error loading shared library: Dynlink.Error (Dynlink.Cannot_open_dll "Failure(\"Cannot resolve camlGzip\")")
[kernel] User Error: cannot load plug-in 'frama-c-wp': cannot load module
  Details: error loading shared library: Dynlink.Error (Dynlink.Cannot_open_dll "Failure(\"Cannot resolve camlWhy3__Ident\")")
[kernel] User Error: Deferred error message was emitted during execution. See above messages for more information.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Looks like that the Frama-C plugin system doesn't work with the Windows loader. My suggestion is to use WLS (Windows Linux Subsystem) or just Linux either through Docker or Virtualbox. If it doesn't work for you, then it is better to submit an issue to the Frama-C issue tracker.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a frama-c specific issue better resolved on their issue tracker. https://frama-c.com/html/bug_reporting_guidelines.html

Comment: @ivg, sorry to nitpick, but it's WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), and yes, this is the preferred way for [installing Frama-C under Windows](https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/blob/master/INSTALL.md#installing-frama-c-on-windows-via-wsl)

Comment: @ivg@Virgile，please visit the website  https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/  I have tried to use cygwin+windows ,but it didn't work.

Comment: @Virgile Yes, for latest version of frama-c, WSL is the recommended solution for frama-c on windows. But it seems that frama-c should be supported in Cygwin, at least for former version of frama-c.